# getting started with Single Sign On / Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-authentication

First off, The Problem:

We have a Web App with a Flash front-end that talks to our ASP.NET web service via SOAP which then deals with all of our server side code (C#).

Right now, we implement a simple user sign on in our application, storing the info in our MSSQL DB.

A client has requested what I understand to be Windows authentication through our application using the currently logged in user.

So, I have been tasked with investigating this. Nobody, including myself, has any experience in this area.

I have been reading up on some basic Active Directory information, and some simple tutorials. I understand how to get access to the directory using ADSI through code. What I'm really interested in seeing is how the entire thing should be architected. I don't want to throw together a hacky solution.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial for this kind of thing or have any advice on getting started? More importantly, does this even sound viable?

I know I haven't given much information, but feel free to ask and I will provide answers.

Thanks.

---

Edit:

Will, to give you an idea of the scope of this, the network will include every computer in a large hospital. So yes, this is huge. Clearly I need to start small. I would like to come up with something that will work at my office first. Maybe ~10 Windows computers on a single domain. One Domain Controller.

I am also open to any good books on the subject.

Comment: You're getting into some serious stuff here.  And how you do it depends strongly on your network architecture.  You should probably (and clearly) describe or even diagram how your network is laid out.  If everything is on one machine, that's easy.  But if you have two or more machines involved on the same network, it starts getting complicated.  Two or more domains and you're in for a world of hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to tie into Active Directory you will want to take a look at the **[System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx)** namespace.  The implementations can vary wildly depending on your system architecture, but this should give you a good starting point.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks. I am starting to mess around with the Directory Services namespace to see whats available. There is so much involved. I dont know where to begin.

Comment: @SP - Yes there is a lot of information to wade through.  I would start with creating a System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry object and then try doing a search for an object in the directory by using System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher object.  Hope this helps.